# Discord.py Clean command deletes pins

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get this command to stop deleting pinned messages. I've seen a few topics here about that but none of them seem to be coded quite right for my bot. Here is the code I have right now:

```
@commands.command(aliases=["c", "C", "Clean"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clean(self, ctx, amount: int):
        await ctx.message.delete()
            amount = amount
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0x4a3d9a, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Clear", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Success", value=f"Successfully cleaned {amount} messages.")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text="NewHorizon Development | https://NewHorizon-Development.netlify.app", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=3)


    @clean.error
    async def clean_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0x4a3d9a, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Whoopsie", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Command Error", value="I'm sorry. but it seems I do not know how many messages you want me to clean.\n\nPlease try again and specify the amount of messages for me to clean")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text="NewHorizon Development | https://NewHorizon-Development.netlify.app", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=3)
        else:
            if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0x4a3d9a, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name="Whoopsie", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Command Error", value="I'm sorry, but it seems you do not have the permissions to use this command.")
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text="NewHorizon Development | https://NewHorizon-Development.netlify.app", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=3)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

As suggested by the first comment, I've tried using:

```
@commands.command(aliases=["c", "C", "Clean"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clean(self, ctx, amount: int):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        amount = amount
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x4a3d9a, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name="Clear", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Success", value=f"Successfully cleaned {amount} messages.")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text="NewHorizon Development | https://NewHorizon-Development.netlify.app", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=3)
```

However this still deletes user pins.

I am using the rewrite branch if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use rewrite:
`await ctx.channelpurge(limit=amount, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)`

If not, you can use `purge_from`:
`await self.bot.purge_from(ctx.channel, limit=amount, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)`

Comment: also if it helps. i use the rewrite branch.

Comment: ok oddly enough it actually works now. no idea why it didn't work the first time i tired it. ty for the help.